# rest_framework serializer with natural keys

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This might be a basic question but I am a total newbie to `django` and `rest framework`.

In django, we have a [`natural key`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/serialization/#natural-keys) with the help of which we can write foreign key elements into a json file during the serialization process. Can this also be done with the serializers in Rest Framework?

Comment: It has RelatedField , http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django REST Framework has `RelatedField` and `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

Check it: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations